Share an Office365-calendar with external Office365 guest user
I am trying to give an external Office365 Business user read access to an Office365-calender.
I have did the following already:

In the admin-center of Office365 I enabled external sharing company-wide (Settings > Org Settings > Services | Calendar) for users with a Microsift 365 or Exchange
I added the external guest user to our Microsoft Entra
Via powershell I can see that this user is of recipientType 'mailUser'

The calendar exists

When I try the following command, it fails:

Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity calendar.owner@domainA.be:\Kalender -User external.user@domainB.be -AccessRights LimitedDetails 

It returns following error:
Add-MailboxFolderPermission: |Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.InvalidSharingRecipientsException|You cannot share with some recipients.

I have allowed calendar sharing like you in the Office365 Administration Org settings.
I have created a name mail user like you named "mail user" with external email address mailuser@external.com.
Using the following code I can add permissions using the mail users external e-mail address.
 Add-MailboxFolderPermission -AccessRights "Reviewer" -Identity "test:\calendar" -User (Get-MailUser "mail user").PrimarySmtpAddress

This outputs:
FolderName           User                 AccessRights                           SharingPermissionFlags
----------           ----                 ------------                           ----------------------
Calendar             Mail User            {Reviewer}


thank you for your response. But when I execute your command, I retrieve the same exception as before  Add-MailboxFolderPermission: |Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.InvalidSharingRecipientsException|U kunt niet delen met enkele geadresseerden. It looks like something in my AD external user is not setup properly or in my organisation, but I have no clue where to start.
